# Postgresql: Group rows in a row and add array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

Hi i have a table like this;

```
+----+----------+-------------+
| id | room_id  |    house_id |
+----+----------+-------------+
|  1 |        1 |           1 |
|  2 |        2 |           1 |
|  3 |        3 |           1 |
|  4 |        1 |           2 |
|  5 |        2 |           2 |
|  6 |        3 |           2 |
|  7 |        1 |           3 |
|  8 |        2 |           3 |
|  9 |        3 |           3 |
+----+-------+----------------+
```

and i want to create a view like this

```
+----+----------+-------------+
| id | house_id |       rooms |
+----+----------+-------------+
|  1 |        1 |     [1,2,3] |
|  2 |        2 |     [1,2,3] |
|  3 |        3 |     [1,2,3] |
+----+-------+----------------+
```

i tried many ways but i cant gruop them in one line

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_agg()`:

```
select house_id, array_agg(room_id order by room_id) as rooms
from t
group by house_id;
```

If you want the first column to be incremental, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select row_number() over (order by house_id) as id, . . .
```